# Swift Sqlite model binding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I started programming on iOS and I come from ASP.NET MVC.
I am trying to find a way to bind the models to a database, or at least something similar to entity framework model binding, I want to create two models like so:

```
class A{
 let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
 let name = Expression<String?>("name")
}

class B{
 let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
 let name = Expression<A>("A")
}
```

I would like to know if this is possible or could someone point me to the right direction and when I fetch data I want to fill my models from sqlite

Thanks in advance
and sorry if I was unclear in my question.

Comment: You might consider Core Data (see [What is Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)), which might be a better analogy to EF than just using SQLite directly. You're still storing data in SQLite, but you're working with model objects rather than interfacing with the database directly. It's not a perfect analog to EF, but it's closer...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it I think this might be the thing I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

The [GRDB.swift](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) SQLite library focuses on helping applications loading models (aka records) from the database: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#records

Maybe that's just what you are looking for:

```
let persons = try Person.fetchAll(db) // [Person]
for luckyPerson in try Person.filter(isLucky).order(name).fetchAll(db) { person in
    print(person.name)
}
if let person = try Person.fetchOne(db, key: 1) {
    print(person.name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me too